# CSS Styling Input Boxes - IE7 not picking up any styles

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

Below is a preview of what I have:

[image]

To the left, I have a nice styled select box which works on all browsers except IE7.  To the right is what shows up in IE7.  It's not a huge deal but it would be nice to get it working in IE7 to look nice like the other browsers.

Do I need to do anything differently in regards to styling?

**CSS Code:**

```
select {
    margin:0 10px 10px 0; 
    background:#d6d6d6 url(../images/select_bg.png) repeat-x;  
    border:1px solid #9c9c9c; 
    padding:5px; 
 }
```

Just wondering why this would happen and if I need to do something else in order to get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Just wondering why this would happen and if I need to do something
>   else in order to get it to work.

It happens because IE 7 does not support a background image for the select element.

AFAIK, [there is not much else you can do without JavaScript](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/).